# Laravel - additional info in ManyToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables likes this:

```
Car
 -id
 -name
 -production_start
 -etc

Option
 -id
 -name
 -price

Options_Cars
 -id_option
 -id_car
 -in_basic
```

With code like this:

```
class Cars extends Eloquent {     
    public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Options','options_cars','id_car','id_option');
    }
}
```

How do I retrieve the in_basic field for each option inside a view?

Comment: What is the purpose of the 'in_basic' column - I don't think it should belong where it currently is and that's probably the right question to ask first.

Comment: @Barnabas Denotes whether an option is included in the basic package of a car

Comment: well that may mean if it's in basic, it is not an option anymore? I see though where it is going... I will submit an answer now to give you an idea of a different approach.

Comment: @Robus Just use `withPivot('in_basic')` in the relation definition and it will be accessible through pivot model `$option->pivot->in_basic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('foo', 'bar');
```

makes `$model->pivot->foo` and `$model->pivot->bar` available to you.

This works in both L4 and L5.

Answer (score 1):

I probably would extend on your schema and add another table to distinguish between a basic model of a car and one with extras added, but still keeping all options as building blocks. So for example...

```
Car
  -id
  -name
  -production_start
  -etc
Option
  -id
  -name
  -price
  -etc
Cars_BasicOptions
  -car_id
  -option_id
Cars_ExtraOptions
  -car_id
  -option_id
```

But this above also brought me to a new question - as the Option has a price tag, it is no longer generic. Consider metallic painting as an option - would that be the same price for a Fiat Punto as for a Mercedes SLS-AMG? I doubt it... So Option as you think of it may not be appropriate at all to be that generic. Depending on your business logic, it may be even more appropriate to do something like this:

```
Car
  -id
  -name
  -production_start
  -etc
Option
  -id
  -car_id
  -name
  -price
  -in_basic
  -etc
```

And of course if you want to handle options separately, you can move it into a different table, like...

```
Car
  -id
  -name
  -production_start
  -etc
Option
  -id
  -name
Car_Option
  -car_id
  -option_id
  -price
  -in_basic
  -etc
```

This may be even closer to your original idea. Helps?